# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen kommissarisch und interim?

Tags: meaning

Gibt es Unterschiede zwischen den beiden Begriffen?

- kommissarischer Manager
- Interim-Manager

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ich denke, dass die Antwort von IQV zwar schon recht gut ist, dass der wesentliche Unterschied aber nicht erfasst wird, insbesondere, weil der Unterschied zwischen *zeitlich befristet* und *vorläufig* nicht so klar ist – mir jedenfalls nicht.

Beide Begriffe haben gemeinsam, dass sie im Gegensatz zu *eigentlich* stehen. Sowohl der kommissarische als auch der Interim-Träger eines Amtes oder Titels sind nicht die vollgültigen, eigentlichen Amtsträger, sondern stehen unter irgendeinem Vorbehalt. Deswegen kann es sein, dass diese Begriffe in der Alltagssprache oft nicht differenziert werden.

Der Begriff *kommissarisch* ist aber ein Terminus technicus und hat in juristischen Kontexten eine klare Bedeutung, die *kommissarisch* von *Interim-* unterscheidet: Der Unterschied besteht darin, dass dieser Vorbehalt bei *kommissarisch* sich auf die **Legitimationsgrundlage** bezieht, während er sich bei *Interim-* auf die **Endgültigkeit** der Besetzung bezieht.

Zwei Beispiele, an denen die Abgrenzung deutlich wird:

**kommissarisch**: Wenn in einem Verein auf der Mitgliederversammlung kein neuer Vorstand gewählt werden kann, dann bleibt der alte Vorstand *kommissarisch* im Amt. Hier muss der Begriff *kommissarisch* gewählt werden, weil der Vereinsvorstand sein Amt nicht auf dem üblichen Legitimationsweg erhalten hat. (Der Vorstand muss hier, logisch gesehen, auch nicht unbedingt ein Interimsvorstand sein, weil es sein kann, dass der Vorstand gar nicht neu besetzt wird – wenn es beispielsweise keine Kandidaten oder Kandidatinnen gibt. Es ist also denkbar, dass ein kommissarischer Vorstand die volle Wahlperiode über im Amt ist.)

**Interim-**: Der Fußballtrainer, der vom Vorstand des Vereins vorerst eingesetzt wird, bis ein neuer Trainer gefunden wird, nachdem der vorherige Trainer plötzlich entlassen worden ist, ist definitiv ein *Interimstrainer*. Er ist keinesfalls ein *kommissarischer Trainer*, weil er auf dem üblichen Legitimationsweg berufen wurde (vom Vorstand eingesetzt).

Daraus lässt sich die folgende Merkhilfe ableiten: Da viele Legimitationsverfahren heute Wahlen vorsehen, steht *kommissarisch* häufig im Gegensatz zu *gewählt*, *Interim-* hingegen steht nicht im Gegensatz zu *gewählt*.

Comment: Du bringst mehr Klarheit in die Sprache als üblicherweise dort vorhanden ist. Will sagen: Vermutlich sind sich die meisten Benützer dieser Wörter der feinen Unterschiede v.a. bezüglich der Legitimationsgrundlage gar nicht bewusst. Aber immerhin, es ist ja gut, zu versuchen, solches Bewußtsein zu wecken.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Es geht mir nicht darum, ein Bewusstsein zu wecken, d.h. die Sprache zu verändern (ich denke, das sollte hier auf SE generell nicht getan werden), sondern ich versuche, die Sprachrealität zu beschreiben. Da _kommissarisch_ ein terminus technicus ist, kann es durchaus sein, dass die Abgrenzung außerhalb des juristischen Sprachgebrauchs nicht so klar ist. Ich bin mir aber sehr sicher, dass die Bedeutung innerhalb des juristischen Sprachgebrauchs genau diese ist. Ich habe meine Antwort geändert, um das genauer darzustellen - danke für den Hinweis!

Comment: Nur zur Ergänzung, es gibt auch den Begriff des [Interim-Managements](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interim-Management), ein Terminus aus der Betriebswirtschaft...

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach  Oh, Verzeihung! Es war gar nicht im Sinne einer Kritik ode eines Ergänzungsvorschlags gemeint, vielmehr zum Ausdruck der Bewunderung über die präzise und sinnvolle Unterscheidung!

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Ja, kein Problem. No hard feelings. :-) Die Antwort ist dadurch sicherlich verbessert worden.

Comment: Unabhängig davon, ob sich der Sprecher des - von Dir korrekt beschriebenen -Unterschieds zwischen Legitimation und Dauer bewusst ist oder nicht, gibt es zwei Fälle, in denen es nicht Interims-, sondern nur kommissarisch heißen kann: 1. Der reguläre Funktionsinhaber fällt für einen längeren Zeitraum aus, es wird aber erwartet oder zumindest für möglich gehalten, dass er auf seinen Posten zurückkehrt - dann wird jemand seine Position kommissarisch ausfüllen, das kann sogar der ordnungsgemäß eingesetzte Stellvertreter sein.

Comment: 2. Der bisherige Funktionsinhaber wird nicht zurückkommen, jemand anderes (tendenziell mit einer gleich hohen oder sogar höheren Position) übernimmt vorübergehend die Funktion *zusätzlich* zu seiner eigentlichen Aufgabe - um beim Fußballbeispiel zu bleiben: der Trainer wurde gefeuert, der Manager oder Klub-Präsident übernimmt kommissarisch das Training, bis ein neuer (hauptamtlicher) Trainer verpflichtet wurde.

Answer (score 6):

Die beiden Begriffe "kommissarisch" und "Interim" sind sehr ähnlich, unterscheiden sich in dem Kontext aber leicht.

Ein kommissarischer Manager übernimmt die Funktion vorläufig, beispielsweise weil der eigentliche Funktionsträger längere Zeit erkrankt ist oder kein geeigneter Nachfolger gefunden wird.
Der Begriff kommt aus dem Lateinischen: *commissarius = Beauftragter*.

Ein Interim-Manager übernimmt eine Funktion zeitlich befristet, um ein bestimmtes Ziel zu erreichen, beispielsweise um ein Projekt umzusetzen oder um einen Unternehmensteil zu sanieren.
Dieser Begriff kommt ebenfalls aus dem Lateinischen, nämlich *ad interim = unterdessen, einstweilen*.

Das ist allerdings ein sehr subtiler Unterschied und die Grenzen verschwimmen oft. So wird der Begriff "Interim-Manager" auch oft im Sinne des "kommissarischen Mangers" verwendet, wenn eine längere Vakanz zu überbrücken ist.

Oft wird die Nutzung des Begriffs wahrscheinlich durch persönliche Vorlieben, Stil oder Tradition bestimmt. So ist die "kommissarische Leitung" regelmäßig in Behörden zu finden.

Comment: *Kommissarisch* bedeutet üblicherweise, dass die betreffende Position nicht über das eigentlich vorgesehene Verfahren besetzt worden ist. Die Position wird dann vorübergehend z.B. von dem Inhaber einer anderen Position mit übernommen, bis sie regulär neu besetzt wird. Insofern bedeuten beide Begriffe in der Praxis oft dasselbe.